# Org mode converting spaces to tabs when evaluating source?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I am testing out the Babel feature in org-mode, with this small block.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results verbatim :exports both                                                     
banner -w 35 e                                                                                                                  
#+END_SRC                                                                                                                          

#+RESULTS:                                                                                                                         
:              #####                                                                                                               
:            #########                                                                                                             
:          ####  #   ###                                                                                                           
:          #     #     ##                                                                                                          
:         ##     #      #                                                                                                          
:          #     #     ##                                                                                                          
:          #     #   ###                                                                                                           
:            #   #####
```

(The `banner` command writes an ASCII art heading. So in this example I'm just printing out an `e`, sideways. The leading whitespace characters are all spaces.)

I try to export this to TeX, and in the TeX file I see that some of the leading spaces have been replaced with tabs; namely any group of 8 spaces gets replaced with a tab. Therefore the lines don't show up properly when the TeX is exported to PDF. I had a look at the source code of `org` and I found that it might be `org-trim` causing this. There's also the option `org-src-preserve-indentation`, but that doesn't seem to act on the output of the source code, only the source itself. Can I stop `org` from converting the whitespaces to tabs?

EDIT: Just tried `sed 's/<tab-character>/        /g'` on the TeX file to replace each tab with 8 spaces, and the problem is fixed immediately. So org must be changing them somewhere, I just need to know where...

EDIT #2: Apparently there is some [normalizing](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob;f=lisp/org-element.el;h=bf76bd40e2650b4d9cbea8e0b4f8c37be3095886;hb=96a9542ae1153a0c8003d9e80a48d1558b89b50a#l4566) going on that might be the issue. Listing here for reference.

Answer (score 4):

This usually fixes for me so LaTeX comes out fine:

```
(setq org-src-preserve-indentation nil 
      org-edit-src-content-indentation 0)
```

Also, you could use this instead of sed:

```
M-x untabify
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `untabify`. I set the variables at the top of the .org file with `# -*- org-src-preserve-indentation: nil; org-edit-src-content: 0; -*-` and reloaded the buffer, but this doesn't seem to change the exported TeX.

Comment: @Charles, I usually set those types of variables in my init file and load them before org is loaded. I do not know if that makes any difference in your case.

Comment: Hold on, shouldn't `org-src-preserve-indentation` in your answer be set to `t`? The manual says, `By default, the value is nil, which means that when code blocks are evaluated during export or tangled, they are re-inserted into the code block, which may replace sequences of spaces with tab characters. ***When non-nil, whitespace in code blocks will be preserved during export or tangling, exactly as it appears.***`

Comment: `0` is `non-nil`.

Comment: I'm talking about `org-src-preserve-indentation`, which, in your answer, you recommended to set as nil. It turns out that setting it to `t` fixes the TeX output! Now it's just that TeX "normalizes" the whitespace by deleting it in rectangular vertical chunks. But I think I have almost solved it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Doing the simple</strike>

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

fixed it for me...

Org mode doesn't really like tabs anyway, it seems, so this works just fine.

EDIT: Nope nope nope I'm an idiot. But this worked for me, at least (I use two space tabs, change that as necessary):

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process '("sed -ie 's/  /  /g' %f"
                        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
                        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
                        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

Comment: What are you doing with this code? Are you `setq`ing a variable, or calling the function? You can just delete your currently-commented-out text if it's not an answer.