# org-mode setting to preserve spacing in SRC code, with verbatim latex output to pdf

Tags: org-export, latex, whitespace, tabs, source

Like [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24283/org-mode-converting-spaces-to-tabs-when-evaluating-source), when I indent within a SRC code block in org-mode, 8 consecutive spaces are converted to a tab. Moreover, when I export to LaTeX 8 consecutive spaces are converted to tabs in the resultant `.tex` output. This is a problem as my 
LaTeX (pdflatex / xelatex) convert tabs in `verbatim` mode to a single space. This means my source code's indentation is off. A http://tex.stackexchange.com poster was told to [use fancyvrb](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231083/how-to-stop-verbatim-from-converting-tabs-to-spaces), but that doesn't immediately solve my problem.

I want to use org-mode to write these documents, `C-c '` to edit source blocks, and `C-c C-e l p` to turn my org-mode files into pdfs.

What options do I have to, for instance:

- make org-mode SRC blocks export as `fancyvrb`'s Verbatim mode **OR**
- prevent my org-mode's indentation mechanism and my export to LaTeX from turning 8 spaces into a tab **OR**
- post-process the exported LaTeX and transform the tabs into 8 spaces?

And how can I make this setting the default for my org-mode? I would like not to have to include this same boilerplate in all of my org-mode files that I intend to use with it, and I would like to avoid having a special latex compilation command to have to use for the tex files I generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(setq TeX-auto-untabify 't)
```

Adding that to the `.emacs` file solves the problem wonderfully.

Comment: Mark your own question as the solution if it solved the problem you had.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to "prevent my org-mode's indentation mechanism and my export to LaTeX from turning 8 spaces into a tab", consider setting `org-src-preserve-indentation` to a non-NIL value. If `org-src-preserve-indentation` is set to NIL, org will remove leading whitespace and reindent the code block.